# Affine-regular hexagon in convex body

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, affine-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

An affine-regular $n$-gon is a non-degenerate affine image of the regular $n$-gon. It seems to be a standard fact in combinatorial geometry that inside every convex compact set $K\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ with nonempty interior it is possible to inscribe at least one affine-regular hexagon so that its vertices belong to the boundary of $K$. This is stated, for example, [here](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/AG/3-1/3_45.pdf).

How does one prove this? I am not able to find an accessible reference that contains the proof. Is there "typically" a unique inscribed hexagon?

Comment: try Convex Sets and Their Applications, by Steven R. Lay

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221319